# Secret Santa sorting hat in R

Tags: r

I am trying to simulate a sorting hat with constraints for our yearly secret santa.

The program should randomly assign gift-givers that do not overlap with last year's assignment.

I tried to put everything in a `while` loop. However I do not think the constraints are working.

Here is what I have so far:

```
# set up data
rm(list = ls())
names <- c('sally', 'linus', 'lucy', 'snoopy', 'peppermint', 'pigpen')
# hard code the past
past <- c("lucy", "pigpen", "peppermint", "sally", "snoopy", "linus")
df <- data.frame("names" = names, "past" = past)

# sorting hat
hat <- function(x) {
  success <- FALSE
  while (!success) {
    # pick name from hat
    pick <- sample(names, replace = F)
    # create  T/F vectors to see if any picks are same as self or past
    #   then bind them into object so the success test returns a single T/F value
    check_name <- c(pick == names)
    check_past <- c(pick == past)
    check = cbind(check_name, check_past)
    # success = T if any elements of test are TRUE
    success <- TRUE %in% check   
  }
  x$pick = pick
  return(x)
}

> hat(df)
   names       past       pick
1      sally       lucy     pigpen
2      linus     pigpen      linus
3       lucy peppermint peppermint
4     snoopy      sally      sally
5 peppermint     snoopy     snoopy
6     pigpen      linus       lucy
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is almost fine, you should just have `success <- !(TRUE %in% check)` instead of `success <- TRUE %in% check`. Something a bit shorter:

```
set.seed(2015)
hat <- function(x) {
  pick <- sample(x$names, replace = FALSE)
  while(any(x$past == pick | x$names == pick))
    pick <- sample(x$names, replace = FALSE)
  x$pick <- pick
  x
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. Shorter, too. Any idea why my `while` loop ignored the constraints? **Edit**. Sorry, I didn't see your comment above the code fragment until after I posted my comment. Many thanks.

Comment: If your loop needs to run at least once (as in this case) you are better off using `repeat` instead of `while`.  ("repeat" loops are often called "do-while" or similar in other languages.)